# Celery/Django worker detect when there are no jobs left

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Celery/Django worker connected via RabbitMQ to the server.  When the worker finishes a job I want it to terminate if there are no jobs left - how can I check there are no jobs left in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

kill the pid when task is finisched throw psutil.

For example:

```
import psutil
import os

@celery.task
def my_task():
    pid=os.getpid() # get the worker pid
    # your code
    return pid # or store it somewhere

def task_caller()
    result = my_task.apply()
    if no_more_jobs('my_queue'): 
        kill_worker(result)
    
def kill_worker(pid):
    try:
        proc = psutil.Process(pid=pid)
        for child in proc.children(recursive=True):
            child.kill()
        proc.kill()
        return True
    except Exception:
        # manage exception
        return False

def no_more_jobs(queue):
    # edit below params
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    q = channel.queue_declare(queue)
    return q.method.message_count == 0
```

Note: This is a basic example which needs to be edited depending your producer/consumer logic

Comment: Thanks, but it's actually the no_more_jobs() call I need help with

Comment: Edited answer. Having some code can be useful